# How to relay from a remote location with SMTP by using iis7

Tags: smtp, iis-6, windows-server-2008

I am kind of confused when it comes to the iis6 smtp server. On my local network everything works perfectly because I've assigned a few IP address that are granted permission to Connection and Relay.

Now, when I am out of my network, say McDonald's, how do I assess my SMTP server located on my work network located remotely?

What is confusing to me is that in the properties dialog box for the smtp virtual servers there is an Access tab which request IP address for the Connection and the Relay.

There is also a tab called Delivery and it is once again asking for Outbound Security. Why is it asking for Outbound security when I've already given a specific IP address Access, back when I set up the Connection & Relay.

It gives me the feeling that I'm giving access in the form of Connection and Relay by giving a machine or device Connection & Relay access via IP address.

**Now when I click on the Messages tab I am being asked once again to chose one of three setting for the Outbound Security. If I've already given some machine or device assess to connect and relay by their IP address, why am i being asked to do this a second time with-in the body of the Deliver tab?

How can I connect to my remote SMTP server from some remote location?

If anyone can shed some light on this that would be awesome!

Thanks!

The first snapshot is the Access Tab
The second snapshot is the Delivery Tab with the Outbound Security button clicked to open the Outbound Secure dialog box.

[image: Access-Tab]

[image: Delivery-Tab]

**Access Tab**

Answer (score 0):

The SMTP service has two different sets of configurations: one for how clients are allowed to access the SMTP service (=incoming connections), and one for how the SMTP service connects to other SMTP servers (=outgoing connections). Both of these can contain credentials, but they are used for different purposes.

The main problem with accessing your own SMTP server when you are at another location is the fact that most ISPs block outgoing SMTP traffic. Most ISPs want their customers to send emails using their server (i.e. they want to control your sending so you cannot send spam from their network).

To use your own SMTP server from remote locations, it is best to configure it to listen on another TCP port that is not blocked **and** secure access to that port with username and password (otherwise someone will find your SMTP service and use it to relay a few gazillion spam messages).